# Search function failing to return results in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am writing a macro to produce analysis of information in Excel and am having problems with the search function.

I will use this to search multiple cells on a sheet called "Master Data" containing lists of data.  An example of the content of a single cell is as follows:
EXT 10DEC, PCR 11DEC, LC 12DEC, FR 24DEC

I would like to search within each cell for specific information concatenated from specific text and variable data specified in cell B10 on another sheet called "Control".  I have the following code to do this:

```
MyValue = "EXT" & " " & Worksheets("Control").Range("B10").value
Range("J2").Formula = "=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(MyValue, RC[-1])),""EXT"",""N"")"
```

So, using the example data above, if I enter 10Dec in cell B10, I expect the code to search cell I2 for "EXT 10DEC" and, if it finds it, return "EXT" in J2.  If it doesn't find it, it should return "N".

My problem is that this code returns "N" for everything.  I have tested the MyValue variable, the ISNUMBER and IF functions and can't find any issues.

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 2):

You're using the literal string "MyValue" and not the value of that variable:

```
MyValue = "EXT" & " " & Worksheets("Control").Range("B10").value
Range("J2").Formula = "=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(""" & MyValue & """, RC[-1])),""EXT"",""N"")"
```